# html multiple select unable to get the values with php

Tags: php, html, select

I know this question was asked before but the answers don't work for me.

My Code:
I have this html select box:

```
<select name="usergroups[]" id="usergroups" multiple="multiple" style="width:210px;">
<?php 
$result = dbselect("SELECT * FROM Groups");
foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<option value='".$row['GroupName']."'>".$row['GroupName']."</option>";
    }   
?>
</select>
```

The options for the select box come from a database and it worked fine. It shows  what should be displayed.

Then i want the selected options to work with them in my php code.

```
$usGroups = $_POST['usergroups[]'];
$usgr = implode(",",$usGroups);
```

I convert the array to a string to save the values in my database.

My problem:
It seems that with $_POST I don't get the values and I really don't know why?

Is it because I fill in the options in a dynamic way?
Or is a mistake in the code which I'm not able to see?

It seems so simple but I don't get it.

Thank's for any help! (and sorry for my bad english...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after submit use:

```
var_dump($_POST)
die();
```

or:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST)
die();
```

you can as well check like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['usergroups']) {
 //do something
}
```

to see if the value is in those super globals.
If it's not there then you're not passing it right from the form.

Remember that you need to set method of FORM to POST for this to work ($_REQUEST will have values of either post or get).

Depending on which data you're sending from your form you might need to add enctype="multipart/form-data", i.e. 
`<form action="/someaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now I know that php don't get any values. But it should because i have many other checkboxes and radio buttons and php get the value from them but not from this stupid little select box.

Comment: specifying "multipart/form-data" as enctype is wrong in this case, you can leave default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" enctype to be able to easily manipulate posted data with $_POST superglobal

Comment: That's interesting :) are you sending it with Ajax/JS or just submitting over standard form/php?

Comment: I submit it with Ajax.

Comment: ok, open your page, after that open chrome developer tools and click on network tab. with this open click on the button that makes the ajax request. You should see this request in Network tab under XHR tab.  After you click on it in there you will see a panel on the right side showing you headers of request/response and preview of the response. Make sure that data you're missing (usergroups) is present in the form_data/request data in that tab. If you click preview it will show you response from your server. Make sure all the data is set right in the request.

Comment: I get it! Thanks for the tip with Ajax. It was a missing var in my ajax submit! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the name of POST variable wrong, you should do it like this:

```
$usGroups = $_POST['usergroups'];
$usgr = implode(",",$usGroups);
```

> Don't use array brackets to fetch the variable in PHP

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried it with and without brackets. Both the same result. I don't think that this is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r` the $_POST variable, to see whats coming in it?

Comment: Now i know that php don't get any value but I don't know why

Comment: actually brackets will be ignored as submitting the form, as it is going to get url encoded

Comment: But you've mentioned that its a `POST` request, then why its going as URL encoded!

Comment: because form default enctype is **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**, check html specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype) for HTML5, [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype) for HTML4 and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#form) for HTML3.2